# Can't destroy cookie and session in same time?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to destroy visitors `cookie` and `session` at same time when he/she logs out. Like this:

```
setcookie($id, '', time()-13600, "/");
unset($_SESSION[$id]);
```

Although `cookie` destroys but user is still logged in because `session` not destroying.

> Note: I can't use `session_unset()` because it will destroy all the sessions.

PS: I solved my problem just by not setting session but only cookie, still i can't solve problem i asked above.

Comment: Please update your code code if you're not using sessions.

Comment: @schellingerht That is my second option to solve my problem, but it not solves the question i asked.

Comment: Save the sessions in Redis, configure it easily in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

well you could use session_destroy() in order to unset the session for current user.
the rest of sessions will stay unchanged.
this is how you do it

```
<?php
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

for destroy all sessions use this code

```
<?php
session_destroy();
```

for unset any session you can do it by session : key

```
<?php
unset($_SESSION['key_name']);
```